# How to replicate the frowNow function in moment.js in native js Date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, momentjs

Trying to replicate the fromNow function in moment.js with native JS Date object but getting a date that is one day behind. I'm passing the value as unix it gives the right output when i use moment but giving a wrong date when i use Native JS date

```
const fromNow = targetUnixTimestampInSeconds => {
  const now = new Date();
  const nowInSeconds = Math.floor(now.getTime()/1000);

  // Convert the target Unix timestamp to local time in seconds
  const targetDate = new Date(targetUnixTimestampInSeconds);
  const targetOffsetInSeconds = targetDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60;
  const targetInSeconds =
    Math.floor(targetDate.getTime() / 1000) + targetOffsetInSeconds;

  const diffInSeconds = nowInSeconds - targetInSeconds;
  if (diffInSeconds < 60) {
    return `${diffInSeconds} second${diffInSeconds === 1 ? "" : "s"} ago`;
  } else if (diffInSeconds < 3600) {
    const minutes = Math.floor(diffInSeconds / 60);
    return `${minutes} minute${minutes === 1 ? "" : "s"} ago`;
  } else if (diffInSeconds < 86400) {
    const hours = Math.floor(diffInSeconds / 3600);
    return `${hours} hour${hours === 1 ? "" : "s"} ago`;
  } else if (diffInSeconds < 2592000) {
    const days = Math.floor(diffInSeconds / 86400);
    return `${days} day${days === 1 ? "" : "s"} ago`;
  } else if (diffInSeconds < 31536000) {
    const months = Math.floor(diffInSeconds / 2592000);
    return `${months} month${months === 1 ? "" : "s"} ago`;
  } else {
    const years = Math.floor(diffInSeconds / 31536000);
    return `${years} year${years === 1 ? "" : "s"} ago`;
  }
};
```

this is the function that I have written,

```
const targetUnixTimestampInSeconds = 1689875101441 / 1000; // Convert to seconds
console.log(fromNow(targetUnixTimestampInSeconds)); //this gives 2 days ago
console.log(moment(1689875101441).fromNow()); // this gives 3 days ago
```

I'm expecting the function to give the same output as moment js

Comment: your issue seems to be due to the timezone that moment is working in, compared to what your native js datetime is working in.

Comment: moment might be using UTC, while your "fromNow" function is using some sort of local datetime. check this out and if it works let me know

Comment: Hey @DennysJoseph, I'd be interested to see the solution if you would share it with us. I was also playing around to see if I could simplify it a bit (still getting "2 days ago"  tho :-D); I'm sharing it here in case you find it helpful https://gist.github.com/rjanjic/4b561ddaef6c2592d4b79eff44cb7e41  
Cheers!